# Applying StyleIndexId to multiple cells in row of Excel using OfficeXml

Tags: excel, openxml, openxml-sdk

I'm currently working on a project where I must merge cells together for an Excel document using OpenXml.  I have figured out how to do the merge, however, the styling is off.  The first cell in the merged cells is styled but not the rest.  I need help figuring out how to style the remainder of the merged cells in that particular row.

Important thing to note: I am creating a doc, versus opening.  I've found plenty of examples when opening a doc, not creating.

Below is my current code where I am creating my Merged Cell method.

```
private void InsertMergedCellInRow(Worksheet workSheet, CellValues dataType, string content,
        Row row, int styleIndex, string startCol, string endCol)
    {
        //Create Merge Cells
        MergeCells mergeCells;

        //Check to see if there are other Merge Cells
        if (workSheet.Elements<MergeCells>().Count() > 0)
            mergeCells = workSheet.Elements<MergeCells>().First();
        //There are none, so create one
        else
        {
            mergeCells = new MergeCells();

            //Insert the Merge Cells into the xml
            if (workSheet.Elements<CustomWorkbookView>().Count() > 0)
                workSheet.InsertAfter(mergeCells, workSheet.Elements<CustomWorkbookView>().First());
            else
                workSheet.InsertAfter(mergeCells, workSheet.Elements<SheetData>().First());
        }

        //Create the Merge Cell and append it to the Merge Cells, and then save the Worksheet
        var mergeCell = new MergeCell() { Reference = new StringValue(startCol + ":" + endCol) };
        mergeCells.Append(mergeCell);
        workSheet.Save();

        //Style all cells within range
        var cells = row.Descendants<Cell>().ToList();
        var isFirst = false;
        foreach (var cell in cells)
        {
            //Find first cell for merge
            if (cell.CellReference == startCol)
                isFirst = true;

            //Not found first cell of merged range, so skip ahead
            if (!isFirst)
                continue;

            //Set the Style Index
            cell.StyleIndex = (uint)styleIndex;

            //Found last cell, so escape loop
            if (cell.CellReference == endCol)
                break;
        }

        //Insert your data to specified Cell Reference
        InsertCellInRow(dataType, content, row, styleIndex, mergeCell.Reference);
    }
```

The row passed in was just row = new Row().  Once I come out of this method, I append the row to Sheet Data.  Any help would be appreciated.

*UPDATE*
I finally figured out a solution.  When I begin in the new row, I start off by creating the cells that will be part of the merged cell.  I style them as I want them (like they should appear when merged).  Once that is done, create the merged cell.  Instead of inserting it like I do a normal cell as I had previously, I simply save.  Now the cell is merged, with the proper styling around.  I will put the finalized version of the code up tomorrow morning.

Comment: does it make it any easier if, instead of merging the cells, you use the `Center Across Selection` format. I know this typically makes things easier than Merging Cells when working in Excel, normally. Merged Cells are very difficult to death with, especially, programmatically.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman - "Merged cells are very difficult to *death* with ...". They'll be the death of me as well!  But I agree, if they can be avoided, it's best to not use Merged Cells.

Comment: Agreed, it's a pain.  However, I'm redoing an old report at the bequest of my manager in via OpenXml and the formatting has been requested to remain mostly the same.

Comment: That is the thing @IyaTaisho. You can make the formatting mostly the same and avoid merging the cells. No one can visually tell if the cell is merged for versus "Centered Across the Selection"